# Family of straight lines tangent to $e^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, tangent-line

I just started to learn about Differential equations, I've been reading about families of curves, but I I just got stuck with this problem. I have been Trying to solve it, I have come to find the line for a specific point as (0, 1), which gives me as a result g(x) = ex, but I don't know how to obtain a function that can describe all the lines tangents at all points of $e^x$.

Question:
Find the family of straight lines that are tangents to $e^x$. Find the differential equation that satisfies those lines.

Comment: I don't understand the second part of the question, because the family of lines has two parameters (the point of tangency and the actual point where you do the evaluation). That seems to me to mean that this equation is necessarily a *partial* differential equation but that seems very weird for a question like this. The first part on the other hand is rather simple. As a hint for that, point-slope form is rather convenient for this kind of thing.

Comment: This is called the envelope of a curve. I don't remember the details, but there is a way of deriving a differential equation describing the envelope of a curve given the equation of a curve. I believe it involves looking at the line between $(x, f(x))$ and $(x+h, f(x+h))$ and seeing what happens as $h \to 0$.

Comment: To find the family, do what you did for $(0,1)$ but with $(c,e^c)$. The resulting line should depend on the value of the parameter $c$. (Also check your work for the tangent line at $(0,1)$. What is its slope?)